# How many concurrent connections can I have open at one time when using HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, connection

I am using asynchronous HttpWebRequest BeginGetResponse calls; the docs say that not closing
the stream in the callback may result in running out of connections.

How many connections can I have before "running out"? I am using .NET 3.5.

Also, is there a socket connection pool in the CLR. If so, where is this documented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many? Depends on a lot of things; sockets share the I/O thread pool with all the other asynch I/O mechanisms.

A short if unhelpful answer is "lots". Unless you are creating a server of some sort you are highly unlikely to run out.

There isn't a socket connection pool as such, but there is an asynch I/O thread pool as you may have gleaned from the above. You may find instructive [this blog post from Eric Eilebrecht](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericeil/archive/2008/06/20/windows-i-o-threads-vs-managed-i-o-threads.aspx), whereas a following post is about [what happens next](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericeil/archive/2009/04/23/clr-4-0-threadpool-improvements-part-1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

What you may not realise is that your router will play a big part in this. (And of course memory, internet connection speed etc.) It would be interesting to know what the *theoretical* maximum would be... Depending on your OS, you may need to do some tweaks to allow *many* connections.